# How to prevent gorm from converting custom integer types into strings?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm, uint, tinyint

I have troubles while using gorm with custom types that have integer properties. Gorm tends to convert the integer values into strings for me. There are two separate problems:

**Problem 1:**

I have a custom type defined as follows:

```
type ClientType uint8

const (
    USER ClientType = iota
    SERVER
)

func (t ClientType) String() string {
    return [...]string{"User", "Service"}[t]
```

And then I have a ORM struct for `Client` defined like this:

```
type Client struct {
    ClientID uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    UserID uint64
    ClientType ClientType
    CreatedAt time.Time
}
```

When calling `db.Create(&client)`, gorm automatically invokes the `String()` method on `ClientType`, and causes a data type mismatch in MySQL where I intend to store `ClientType` in a `TINYINT` column called `client_type`.

**Problem 2:**

So I thought if I can't figure out how to override the automatic calling of the `String()` method, I simply renamed the method to `ToString()` and call it when I need it. Now gorm can't invoke it any more, but instead, it casts the integer values into numeric strings instead. So `USER` which is `0`, will now become `'0'` in the resulting SQL statement, and `SERVER` will become `'1'`, although MySQL is able to cast the strings back to integers.

I still wonder what I did wrong to make gorm think I wanted these conversions.

1. Is there a way to override the calling of `String()`, so I can still name the method conventionally?
2. Is it the use of `uint8` that made gorm converts the int to strings, since the other numeric values (ClientID and UserID) using uint64 were not affected by the issue? Is it some sort of caching of the DB schema that made gorm remember the old schema where client_type used to be an `ENUM('User', 'Service')` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per gorm for custom types [Value and Scan](https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html) need to be implemented.

You can try specifying type in struct (replace <TYPE> with column type) too.

```golang
type Client struct {
    ClientID   uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    UserID     uint8
    ClientType ClientType `gorm:"type:<TYPE>"`
    CreatedAt  time.Time
}
```

String() does not seems to be issue as it is not called during creates, but only during finds.

*With `db.LogMode(true)`, it is called during create also, but that seems to be for sql query logging and not for sending to DB.*

**With Log Mode off**

```golang
    db.LogMode(false)
    fmt.Println("Creating")
    db.Create(&Client{ClientID: 9, UserID: 8, ClientType: USER, CreatedAt: time.Now()})
    fmt.Println("Created")

    fmt.Println("Finding")
    db.First(&client)
    fmt.Printf("Found %v\n", client)
```

**output**

```sh
Creating
Created
Finding
String() called with 0
Found {9 8 User 2021-01-28 11:41:51.355633057 +0530 +0530}
```

**With Log Mode on**

```golang
    db.LogMode(true)
    fmt.Println("Creating")
    db.Create(&Client{ClientID: 9, UserID: 8, ClientType: USER, CreatedAt: time.Now()})
    fmt.Println("Created")

    fmt.Println("Finding")
    db.First(&client)
    fmt.Printf("Found %v\n", client)
```

**Output:**

```sh
Creating
String() called with 0
[2021-01-28 11:39:30]  [0.95ms]  INSERT INTO "clients" ("client_id","user_id","client_type","created_at") VALUES (9,8,'User','2021-01-28 11:39:30')  
[1 rows affected or returned ] 
Created
Finding
[2021-01-28 11:39:30]  [1.49ms]  SELECT * FROM "clients"   LIMIT 1  
[1 rows affected or returned ] 
String() called with 0
Found {9 8 User 2021-01-28 11:42:31.245628274 +0530 +0530}
```

Comment: Implementing Value() method on the custom type seems to have done the trick. I basically wrote:

```func (t ClientType) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
 return int64(t), nil
}```

And the issue is resolved. But what I don't understand is why it only seems to accept int64 as the casting type. I have tried uint8, int and so on, but nothing worked, the error message goes like this:

`sql: converting argument $2 type: non-Value type int returned from Value`

Another thing is that String() will still get called somehow, and in gorm v1.20.11, there's no more LogMode().

Comment: [Value](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/go1.15.6/src/database/sql/driver/driver.go#61) has accepted types specified as int64,float64,bool,[]byte,string and time.Time. Thus the error.

Comment: I tried with gorm 1.9. Looks like it is time to upgrade the deps :)